# Not able to add ActionBarActivity to my MainActivity

Tags: android

hi all  i am a newbie in android .I am trying to add ActionBarActivity to my MainActivity but it doesnot show ActionBarActivity however it does show ActionBar and the moment i select ActionBar it negates all the methods however cannot find the ActionBarActivity thing.Any suggestions would be really appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To extend your MainActivity as ActionBarActivity, you need to include **appcompat_v7** library in your project . It is be located at \android-sdk\extras\android\support\v7\ .. Import it as library project.

For more Information please go through [this](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html) link

To import go through following steps..

From the main menu bar, select  command link File > Import.... The Import wizard opens.

Select General > Existing Project into Workspace and click Next.

Choose either Select root directory or Select archive file and click the associated Browse to locate the directory containing the library project (in your case its  \android-sdk\extras\android\support\v7).

Select appcompat , tick the "copy into workspace" checkbox and click Finish to start the import.

To add it your project ...

Right click your project and select properties.

In the Properties window, select the "Android" properties group at left and locate the Library properties at right.

Click Add to open the Project Selection dialog.

From the list of available library projects, select a appcompat and click OK.

When the dialog closes click Apply in the Properties window.

Click OK to close the Properties window.